# Writing Custom Annotation and .java file creation

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, annotations, code-injection

I want to produce my own Annotation and i want it to create .java file. To do so, I use

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
```

However,  i couldnt understand how to trigger processor and init methods in processor ? i guess it has to create .java file in compile time. But it doesnt. How can i trigger Annotation to create .java file ?

I did everything in Android studio and i changed gradle to compile this like a java.

This is processor codes:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {

    for (Element annotatedElement : roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Factory.class)) {

        if (annotatedElement.getKind() != ElementKind.CLASS) {
            error(annotatedElement, "Only classes can be annotated with @%s", Factory.class.getSimpleName());
            return true;
        }

        TypeElement typeElement = (TypeElement) annotatedElement;

        try {

            FactoryAnnotatedClass annotatedClass = new FactoryAnnotatedClass(typeElement);

            if (!isValidClass(annotatedClass)) {
                return true;
            }

            FactoryGroupedClasses factoryClass = factoryClasses.get(annotatedClass.getQualifiedFactoryGroupName());

            if (factoryClass == null) {
                String qualifiedGroupName = annotatedClass.getQualifiedFactoryGroupName();
                factoryClass = new FactoryGroupedClasses(qualifiedGroupName);
                factoryClasses.put(qualifiedGroupName, factoryClass);
            }

            factoryClass.add(annotatedClass);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            error(typeElement, e.getMessage());
            return true;
        } catch (IdAlreadyUsedException e) {
            FactoryAnnotatedClass existing = e.getExisting();
            // Already existing
            error(annotatedElement,
                    "Conflict: The class %s is annotated with @%s with id ='%s' but %s already uses the same id",
                    typeElement.getQualifiedName().toString(), Factory.class.getSimpleName(),
                    existing.getTypeElement().getQualifiedName().toString());
            return true;
        }




    }

    try {

        for (FactoryGroupedClasses factoryClass : factoryClasses.values()) {
            factoryClass.generateCode(elementUtils, filer);
        }

        factoryClasses.clear();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        error(null, e.getMessage());
    }

    return true;
}



  @Override
public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
    super.init(processingEnv);

    typeUtils = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
    elementUtils = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
    filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
    messager = processingEnv.getMessager();

}
```

Comment: i found a solution. We have to add apt plugin to android studio